# How to implement a concat KDF for use with JOSE/JWE/JWT

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, jwe

I'm attempting to write code to decrypt a JWE token in PHP, as the existing libraries don't support the algorithm I need (`A128CBC+HS256`, it's a deprecated algorithm).

My issue is I can't understand how to generate the content encryption key which uses a "Concatenation Key
Derivation Function" (see section 5.8.1 here: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf). The symbols and explanation of the function goes over my head.

I'm getting my values based on [JOSE JSON web algorithms draft 06](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-06.html#rfc.section.4.8.1).

So far, the relevant portion of my code looks like this:

```
// Derive CBC encryption & integrity keys
$shaSize = 256;
$encryptionKeySize = $shaSize / 2;
$integrityKeySize = $shaSize;

// Calculate the key derivation using Concat KDF for the content 
// encryption key
$encryptionSegments = [
    $masterKey,         // Z
    $encryptionKeySize, // keydatalen
    $this->packInt32sBe($encryptionKeySize) . utf8_encode('A128CBC+HS256'), // AlgorithmID
    $this->packInt32sBe(0), // PartyUInfo
    $this->packInt32sBe(0), // PartyUInfo
    'Encryption',           // SuppPubInfo
    $this->packInt32sBe(1), // SuppPrivInfo
];

// Calculate the SHA256 digest
$cek = hex2bin(hash('sha256', implode('', $encryptionSegments)));
```

Possibly relevant, my function for getting a big endian integer:

```
public function packInt32sBe($n)
{
    if (pack('L', 1) === pack('N', 1)) {
        return pack('l', $n);
    }

    return strrev(pack('l', $n));
}
```

The only variable not shown here is `$masterKey` which is the decrypted content master key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did end up solving this. Not sure if it'll ever help anyone else, but just in case:

```
// Derive CBC encryption & integrity keys
$shaSize = 256;
$encryptionKeySize = $shaSize / 2;
$integrityKeySize = $shaSize;

// Calculate the key derivation using Concat KDF for the content 
// encryption key
$encryptionSegments = [
    $this->packInt32sBe(1), 
    $cmk,                              // Z
    $this->packInt32sBe($encryptionKeySize) . utf8_encode('A128CBC+HS256'), // AlgorithmID
    $this->packInt32sBe(0), // PartyUInfo
    $this->packInt32sBe(0), // PartyUInfo
    'Encryption',           // SuppPubInfo
];

// Calculate the SHA256 digest, and then get the first 16 bytes of it
$cek = substr(hex2bin(hash('sha256', implode('', $encryptionSegments))), 0, 16);
```

The only unknown variable here is `$cmk` which is my content master key, aka the "Z" value. In this specific case I got the master key by decrypting it from an XBOX One token request.

Comment: You can optimize your method `packInt32sBe` uing the following single line `return hex2bin(str_pad(dechex($value), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own implementation according to the same specification, but draft #39:

```
<?php

class ConcatKDF
{
    public static function generate($Z, $encryption_algorithm, $encryption_key_size, $apu = "", $apv = "")
    {
        $encryption_segments = array(
            self::toInt32Bits(1),                                                   // Round number 1
            $Z,                                                                     // Z (shared secret)
            self::toInt32Bits(strlen($encryption_algorithm)).$encryption_algorithm, // Size of algorithm and algorithm
            self::toInt32Bits(strlen($apu)).$apu,                                   // PartyUInfo
            self::toInt32Bits(strlen($apv)).$apv,                                   // PartyVInfo
            self::toInt32Bits($encryption_key_size),                                // SuppPubInfo (the encryption key size)
            "",                                                                     // SuppPrivInfo
        );

        return substr(hex2bin(hash('sha256', implode('', $encryption_segments))), 0, $encryption_key_size/8);
    }

    private static function toInt32Bits($value)
    {
        return hex2bin(str_pad(dechex($value), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
    }
}
```

The use is very simple:

```
ConcatKDF::generate("The shared key here", 'A128CBC+HS256', 128);
```

If you have apu and apv parameters:

```
ConcatKDF::generate("Another shared key here", 'A128GCM', 128, "Alice", "Bob");
```